# Does this suggested edit count as vandalism?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, vandalism

I just rejected this [suggested edit on an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/31003313) as vandalism. But thinking about it now, I'm wondering if I made the right choice:

[image: The edit adds a new paragraph under an existing answer for how to add Matplotlib to Python. It is in all caps and says to give up adding Matplotlib.]

Comment: Why would you doubt about that being vandalism? It doesn't get more blatant...

Comment: Yes, it is obvious vandalism

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, I assume we agree it shouldn't be approved, right? Otherwise we have a whole different problem to solve.

What other options do we have?

- No improvement: This one can work as well. The post doesn't get much better with that additional text
- Irrelevant tags: no tags involved, so this option is not a valid choice
- Clearly conflicts with author's intent: Yes, this one works as well. The OP shared what worked for them while the edit tries to convince the world no workable solution exists
- Attempt to reply: Yep, could have been a (bad) comment
- This edit causes harm: would also work but now you have to spend time formulating a reasonable argument to convince that editor to not vandalize content.

That edit yells *vandalism* at us, quite literally. While you had other options to pick from, vandalism is the most appropriate rejection reason in this case.

Comment: Sure, we agree it shouldn't be approved. It's just the option to choose that had me a bit confused.

Comment: @AnnZen It’s the fact that it’s a rant in all caps puts it in vandalism territory. Had the edit simply said, “I don’t think this is worth doing” then either the conflict or reply options would have been the way to go. But this edit is *wildly* inappropriate. Adding damaging content (it would have attracted down votes) is as much vandalism as wiping out important content.